# Updating children values in nHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have database structure with `invoice` and `invoiceParents` with `one-to-many`, `inverse` equals `"false"` and `cascade` equals `"all-delete-orphan"`. Below some snippet from `.hbm` for parent and children.

Parent:

```
<id name="InvoiceId" column="INVOICEKEYID" unsaved-value="0">
   <generator class="sequence">
   <param name="sequence">SOME_SEQ</param>
   </generator>
</id>
...
<bag name="Partners" table="PARTNER" cascade="all-delete-orphan" inverse="false" lazy="true">
      <key column="INVOICEKEYID"/>
      <one-to-many class="Partner"/>
</bag>
```

Children:

```
<id name="Id" column="PARTNERKEYID" unsaved-value="0">
  <generator class="sequence">
     <param name="sequence">ANOTHER_SEQ</param>   
  </generator> 
</id>
...
<many-to-one name="Invoice" column="INVOICEKEYID" class="Invoice" />
```

When I make first `saveOrUpdate(invoice)`, there are INSERT statements, for invoice and invoicePartners, with empty fk and after it UPDATE statements, for invoicePartners, with proper fk. Till this time everything works good.
When I want to update there are only INSERT for invoicePartners, one UPDATE for invoice. There are no UPDATE or DELETE AND INSERT for invoicePartners.
I watch it in vs output.
How does nHibernate work? Firstly I should remove partners and then insert new ones or nHibernate will update it automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This all stems from the owning `bag` (`inverse="false"`) that you have created. As a general rule, never create an owning bag, a `bag` with (`inverse="true"`) provides the ultimate performance, since operations cannot fail.

In this case, I would be careful that you don't end up with a PK violation, NHibernate will not handle the case where you insert a PK violating `invoicePartner`, because you have told it that it is a `bag` and not a `set`. If you don't have a PK and want duplicate `invoicePartner`s then continue with a `bag`, if you don't, switch to `set`. Obviously if your `class` ensures this internally then you will avoid this problem.

Be careful with `bag` generally though, I think you are fine in this case since the mapped entities can be identified, so you should get similar performance to a `set`. But if they cannot be identified, then NHibernate will have to delete all of the children and re-insert them all on any collection change!

---

On addition of an `invoicePartner` to an `invoice`:

The `invoicePartner` is not going to save the relation, since you have told the mapping that you want the `invoice` to own it.

Therefore, on any insert or update to the DB, the `invoicePartner` cannot fill in the `INVOICEKEYID` column.

So the parent `invoice` waits until the `invoicePartner` exists in the DB, then updates the foreign key column, as you observed.

Depending on the default behaviour, this update may be a complete waste of time, since it looks to me that the child would already be saving this foreign key itself!

---

On update of the `invoicePartner` collection:

What you've said doesn't really fit. NHibernate will not call update for `invoice` if all you do is change the `invoiceParnter` collection. There is nothing to update on the `invoice` table!

---

The `cascade="all-delete-orphan"` will ensure that the parent keeps the collection synced with itself, it will insert, update and delete rows from the `invoicePartner` table accordingly as long as you save or update the parent after changing the collection!

But you should set `inverse="true"` on the parent `bag` and add `inverse="false"` to the `invoicePartner` `many-to-one` map. After doing this, check for the case I mentioned in the 3rd paragraph, where NHibernate cannot identify the entities, and make sure that it is indeed associating `invoicePartners` by their identifier and making the changes efficiently.

---

Ref: http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/example-parentchild.html